# Limiting distribution of a first passage time.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following stochastic integral: $$X_{t}^{(\epsilon)}=\epsilon e^{t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}dW_{s},\ \ \ X_{0}=0.$$ Define the hitting time $\tau_{\epsilon}:=\inf\{t\geq 0:|X_{t}^{(\epsilon)}|=1\}$. What is the distribution of $\tau_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: I think that for all $t$ there  is a finite probability that $|X_t|>1$

Comment: By the way the processes are coupled (i.e., $X^{(\epsilon)}_t=\epsilon X^{(1)}_t$), it is clear that $\tau_{\epsilon}$ is non-increasing in $\epsilon$. Then it would make sense to discuss the a.s.-limit of $\tau_{\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon\to0^+$. And this claim will follow once we show that $X^{(1)}$ is a.s.-locally bounded.

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to do so, since I rarely remember any reference related to the sample-path continuity of an Ito integral.

Comment: Nothing simple here. The Laplace transform of the exit time is known, and has a complicated form. Do you really want the exact expression or maybe you are interested in asymptotics when $\epsilon \to 0$?